# how to add each character of a NSString into a NSArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, components, nsarray

I am looking for a way to pass a NSString, which contains 4 charcters that in whole represent a 4 digit number like 0741, I have been looking around and keep coming across this function

```
myArray = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
```

componentsSeparatedByString... what can I do if my components are not separated?

Well, after checking out the link posted below I found NSRange, and have managed to get it working perfectly with this solution below, however it feels abit drawn out and maybe abit more bulky than it needs to be... let me know what you think and what improvements I could make.

```
NSRange MyOneRange = {0, 1};
    NSRange MyTwoRange = {1, 1};
    NSRange MyThreeRange = {2, 1};
    NSRange MyFourRange = {3, 1};

    NSString *firstCharacter = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *secondCharacter = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *thridCharacter = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *fourthCharacter = [[NSString alloc] init];

    firstCharacter = [myFormattedString substringWithRange:MyOneRange];
    secondCharacter = [myFormattedString substringWithRange:MyTwoRange];
    thridCharacter = [myFormattedString substringWithRange:MyThreeRange];
    fourthCharacter = [myFormattedString substringWithRange:MyFourRange];


    NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@, %@", firstCharacter, secondCharacter, thridCharacter, fourthCharacter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options... there's the [`- (unichar)characterAtIndex`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex%3a) method, to start. I suggest reading the NSString documentation (there's a section of methods called "Getting Characters and Bytes").

Comment: Thanks this link was helpfull and is how I have solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 10):

To improvise on your approach,

```
NSRange theRange = {0, 1};
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray array];
for ( NSInteger i = 0; i < [myFormattedString length]; i++) {
    theRange.location = i;
    [array addObject:[myFormattedString substringWithRange:theRange]];
}
```

Comment: +1...but you have a typo. NSString don't have a count method...i guess you meant length

Comment: @deepak can u explain the flow in the string?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work nicely:

```
NSString *dataString = @"0741";
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[dataString length]];
for (int i = 0; i < [dataString length]; i++) {
    NSString *singleCharacter  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [dataString characterAtIndex:i]];
    [characters addObject:singleCharacter];
}
```

Comment: Problem: The size of the datatype returned by `-characterAtIndex:` is wrong for the format specifier `"%c"`. `-characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar` (which is effectively a wide character in spirit, like `wchar_t`), not a `char`. See instead @Deepak's approach of using `-substringWithRange:`, which uses the `NSString` abstraction throughout rather than relying on the underlying character representation.

Comment: With this one could I change the 'NSString *singleCharacter  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [dataString characterAtIndex:i]];' to cast the characterAtIndex:i to a integer?

Comment: yup, I would recommend @Deepak's method as it reads easier (once the clever trick with the NSRange is understood) :)